# How to check if bottom of a SKSpriteNode is inside the current visible scene

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I've been looking at Figure 7-3 in this sprite kit documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Actions/Actions.html but it has left me pretty confused. They seem to give the same name to multiple things e.g., camera/character.

I am in the default `SKScene`, MyScene class. In `initWithSize`, I create a `SKNode *myWorld`, just like the documentation suggests. I then have a series of methods that add my background images to `myWorld`. Scrolling that works just fine, but what I want to do is stop the vertical scrolling when the bottom of the images in `myWorld` reach the bottom of the scene. For the life of me, I cannot figure out how to refer to the bottom of `myWorld`. For the bottom of the scene, I simply do

```
CGPoint sceneFarBottomSide = CGPointMake(0, -self.size.height/2);
```

where `self.anhorPoint` is set to [0.5, 0.5].

How do I refer to the bottom of `myWorld`?

Comment: Check Apple's Adventure code, Moving the camera section: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/CodeExplainedAdventure/KeepingUptoDate/KeepingUptoDate.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013140-CH9-SW1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It ended up being extraordinarily easy to resolve. Thanks Andrey for pointing me to that Apple documentation on the Adventure game, that's what really tipped me off and cleared up some of my understanding. Here's the few lines of code to get the behavior I desired:

```
// Move world
if (monkeyPosition.y > 0 && monkeyPosition.x > 0) {
    [myWorld setPosition:CGPointMake(-monkeyPosition.x, -monkeyPosition.y)];
} else if (monkeyPosition.y > 0 && monkeyPosition.x < 0) {
    [myWorld setPosition:CGPointMake(0, -monkeyPosition.y)];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The edge of myWorld is whatever you set it to be. In other words, myWorld is a node which isn't itself a view or a sprite. It's simply an object that contains sprite or shape children (for example, SKSpriteNodes or SKShapeNodes). When you are adding your sprites to myWorld, keep track of their position. Then use their position to define the "size" of myWorld. You can use this size information along with myWorld.position to know when the (bottom) edge of myWorld is coming up.